# Why does MS SQL Server error on inserting the second row but not on the first row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have an SQL table that will let me insert some rows with a datetime field but not all rows and I can't see why not. The error I get is

**'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'**

To try and work this out I created a temporary table with 1 colum and tried to add the two datetimes that are causing the issue.

`create table #DateTimeTest ( created datetime );`

I then try inserting these two rows

```
insert into dbo.#DateTimeTest (created) VALUES ('2020-06-12 05:46:00.00');
insert into dbo.#DateTimeTest (created) VALUES ('2020-06-19 05:31:00.00');
```

The first row is inserted without any problems, the second-row errors, but I can't understand why.

```
(1 row affected)
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2020-07-15T11:28:43.6451779+01:00
insert into dbo.#DateTimeTest (created) VALUES ('2020-06-19 05:31:00.00');
```

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` is *not* an unambigious format in SQL Server. With the *old* date and time data types (such as `datetime`) it is read differently depending on the language of your `LOGIN`. For example, bizarrely, SQL Server would interpret the value  `'2020-06-19 05:31:00.00'`as being the 6th day of the 19th month is you are anything but American. This is not the case for the newer date and type data types. Therefore it's best to stick to `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn` or `yyyyMMdd` when dealing with literal strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, your date format is YDM rather than YMD.  You can fix this in several ways.

One method is to use an unambiguous date/time format.  In your case, that would include a `T`:

```
insert into dbo.#DateTimeTest (created) VALUES ('2020-06-12T05:46:00.00');
insert into dbo.#DateTimeTest (created) VALUES ('2020-06-19T05:31:00.00');
```

The reason this works is because the YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS format is the standard format for a date/time format in SQL Server -- unambiguously and not affected by `dateformat`.  Similarly YYYYMMDD (note:  no hyphens) is the standard, unambiguous format for a date constant in SQL Server, but YYYY-MM-DD is subject to `dateformat`.

A second method would be to set the `dateformat` to YMD:

```
set dateformat YMD;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c790397090ad1aa833adfe609455652) is a db<>fiddle illustrating this.

A third method would be to explicitly extract the datetime from the string, using a function such as `convert()` -- and perhaps a few string operations as well.

Comment: Can I ask why my date format would be set as YDM? Is this a setting somewhere that I can alter?

Comment: @JGee - the default depends on your login's default language. If, for instance, that's set to `british english` then SQL Server will default your format to `DMY` which it then treats as `YDM` when presented with a `nnnn-nn-nn` pattern, despite nobody in britain interpreting such dates that way.

Comment: Honestly, @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I don't anyone (sane) would read a date and interpret it as `yyyy-dd-MM`. ;)